# How to create custom blocks for a custom theme?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I am new to Drupal and creating a custom Drupal theme from a HTML template.

For some sections, I want to create custom blocks with some specific functionality. For example there is a counter running on right sidebar in HTML template. I want to create a block so users can adjust this block in any region they want.

My main concern is that if users install my Drupal theme on their site, this block should automatically be available in structure block list like main menu and others shows by default.

There is no particular ways defined on any site?

Answer (score -2):

you probably need to create a custom module as well to create a custom block. Look at this http://redcrackle.com/blog/how-create-block-drupal-7  to get an idea how to create a block.

The block you create inside the custom module will always be available at admin/structure/block page. Then it can be assigned to any region.

Comment: i have already gone through this article but if i create a custom module than how can i connect that module to my theme i.e if someone install my theme that module also be installed there..??